# Series diverges or converges

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

How can I show that  $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (\sin n -\sin(πn/2)) / n^2$ converges or diverges?
I tried using the ratio test but it's complicated
I'd say it converges to $0$ since $n^2$ is growing faster than the numerator.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** : $$\left| \frac{\sin n-\sin(\pi n/2)}{n^2}\right|\le \frac{2}{n^2}$$

and use the fact 'Every absolutely convergent series is convergent.'

Comment: I need to find a smaller series that will also converge in this case 1/n² and by the comparison the original series will converge right..

Comment: You don't need a smaller series, you need a larger series, and tetori gave that to you.

Comment: No. You want a *larger* series that converges. A smaller series will tell you that the series diverges if the smaller series diverges.